# Grafana Time Series should not be splitted by label

Tags: time-series, prometheus, grafana

The time series of my internet download speed is splitted by the combination of labels. But I only want to see one single graph.

[image]

Can I accumulate the different label values or just ignore the label "sponsor_host" to get a single line for all values of that metric?

Comment: You can apply `sum()`, `min()`, `max()`, etc to the results to get a single value.

Comment: Side note: beware of pushgateway in this situation. Specifically ["The Pushgateway never forgets series pushed to it and will expose them to Prometheus forever unless those series are manually deleted via the Pushgateway's API."](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/). If you're are using self-written application for exposing metrics, I'd recommend to reconsider use of Pushgateway in favor of pull-based model.

Comment: thanks, using aggregates works but shows each metric twice in the legend, I don't know why.

Comment: I solved the problem by sending the same metric twice with different information. The first without any label and the second with labels to filter out some elements.

Comment: @markalex, thanks for your hint, I am new to pushgateway. I used pushagateway only because it is very simple to push metrics with curl in a batch job.
You mean I should write the metrics to a file and e.g. use the node exportes text file collector to scrape the metrics? This would be a nice solution.

Comment: @dodjango, yes, textfile collector is one way to do it. Another way is to write a simple app, that will listen on some port and response with metrics once requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @markalex and @anemyte, solved by duplicating metrics

Comment: Please read [answer]. Consider adding to your answer what aggregation function you have used and why, and also explaining why you needed to duplicate metrics in your case.